# Where can I find postgresql-8.4-postgis.deb?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, postgresql

I want the deb package.

Comment: Which distro are you using ? Which version of the distro ?

Comment: Ubuntu Karmic Koala 9.10

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned which distro you're using. Assuming Debian,

- [Debian Unstable](http://packages.debian.org/sid/postgresql-8.4-postgis)

Comment: Can I use it on Ubuntu Karmic Koala 9.10?

Comment: Postgis packages are available for PostgreSQL 8.3 in Ubuntu Karmic. I don't think Debian version would work. Then again, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to search for it

```
apt-cache search postgis
```

This should return this, on Karmic, or something close:

```
osm2pgsql - Openstreetmap data to PostgreSQL converter
libpostgis-java - geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- JDBC support
postgis - geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- common files
postgresql-8.3-postgis - geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 8.3
```

To find more info, use `apt-cache showpkg postgis` this will show you, the version and what it depends on:

> Package: postgis Versions: 
>   1.3.5-1ubuntu2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_karmic-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
>
> ...
>
> Reverse Depends:
>   postgresql-8.3-postgis

With a little bit of research you'll find some posts about `postgis 1.3.5`, and `postgrsql 8.4`, it [aparently didn't build cleanly](http://postgis.refractions.net/pipermail/postgis-devel/2009-February/004880.html) and required patching, Postgis 1.3.6 makes special note of [build improvements against 8.4 in the build notes](http://postgis.refractions.net/news/20090506/)

- Improve PostgreSQL 8.4 compile support (Talha Rizwan, Mark Cave-Ayland)

per the 1.3.6 docs.